# Sharing a spreadsheet with script triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I've created a stock watch tool that I'd like to share with the public.  It consists of an editable Google spreadsheet with an associated function that is designed to run on a regular schedule as a trigger to perform the notifications when applicable.

How can I deploy this so that it's easiest for novice users to take advantage of the tool?  Do I have to explain to users how to set up their own triggers?

Or is there a way I can bundle it all together, even with the triggers such that all the user has to do is fill out the spreadsheet?  Or does deploying as a webapp apply here at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [new add-ons for GAS don't support installable triggers yet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) ("But keep the restrictions in mind"), but the old sheets still do (well mine still work). But I can't imagine you can deploy anything via the old script gallery anymore.

So I'd update your script to programmatically create the triggers onInstall() and create a demo version of an old spreadsheet that users could take a copy of. Then keep an eye on installable triggers coming to add-ons when you can deploy it as one of them.